# Vuex mutation payload is undefined

Tags: vuex

Simple VueJS application which uses a Vuex store :

```
const state = {
  arr: []
}
const mutations = {
  'SET_SOME_DATA'(state, payload) {
    console.log('mutations', payload)//here undefined
    state.arr= payload
  }

}

const actions = {
    init: async ({ commit }, payload) => {
    commit('SET_SOME_DATA', await getSomeData(payload.id))
//getSomeData use axios return some arr of objects[{...},{...}]
  }
}
```

Why mutation payload is undefined?